# Table data is not arranged

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, pivot

as i am a beginner so i want to ask how can i run the multiple queries using PHP for the same row to have multiple data in the table in html. i have tried many attempts but nothing worked i am using MYSQL as backend. I know that i have not written code for the first row and second column i.e. the second `<td>` on wicket keeper but the thing is that i want all rounder data to come in the second `<td>` of wicket keeper section. when running this code it is providing the output fine for wicket keeper but for all rounder column the data is starting after the end of wicket keeper data. i know why this problem is occurred but how can i solve this please tell??

CODE HERE:

```
<?php
    $sql="select * from teams where role = 'WicketKeeper'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["name"] ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
    $sql="select * from teams where role = 'AllRounder'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["name"] ?></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

[image: click here to see output]

Comment: Code __must be pasted as text__ here.

Comment: i was trying to paste it but here it is saying that it contains errors even in correct syntax according to language

Comment: I would recommend adding a join so you can query both tables at the same time and access them within a single while loop. That would be the cleanest way to output both columns in the same row

Comment: i have the data in one table

Comment: _"it is saying that it contains errors even in correct syntax according to language"_ - SO doesn't parse the code so the error you got wasn't about the syntax of your code. If you weren't able to paste code with syntax errors here, the site would become pretty useless :-)

Comment: Right, I'm seeing that now. Your table structure seems a little problematic for what you're trying to accomplish. Is there anything that binds those database rows together or is it just the order they are inserted in the database? You might have some data integrity issues down the road if it's the latter.

Comment: Why would you post a picture of text?

Comment: I fear I don’t understand the result you want. Please [edit] your question to explain in more detail.

Comment: because when i was uploading the code then i says that code contains error and the syntax is pretty clear even though.

Comment: i have checked it it is mysqli

Comment: @O.Jones i have altered the code can u please review it once

Comment: i have provided all the information

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good way to generate the rows of the display you showed.

First, use this query:

```
      SELECT name, role FROM teams ORDER BY role DESC;
```

It generates rows in the order you want them, wicketkeepers first.

Then, use this php code to generate your display.

```
<?php
  $sql="SELECT name, role FROM teams ORDER BY role DESC";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $role = $row["role"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $wicketkeeper = $role == "WicketKeeper" ? $name : "";
    $allrounder = $role == "AllRounder" ? $name : "";

    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $wicketkeeper ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $allrounder ?></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

This renders the rows in the result set from your query, placing names in columns according to their roles.

In the general case, this task is known as *pivoting* a table.

**Pro tip 1** Try to avoid `SELECT *` in queries. Instead give the names of the columns you need. This makes your code easier for a stranger to read, and it may make your queries run faster.

**Pro tip 2** Anytime you catch yourself reusing the same query where it only varies by a `WHERE` clause, try to use a single query. This can make your application run faster.